# paramiko.ssh_exception.SSHException: No existing session

Tags: python-2.7, paramiko

I don't understand behavior of paramiko module, could you please help me with it:
example with incorrect behavior is very simple. I have 2 modules:

### module_for_importing.py:

```
import paramiko 
_host = "scl.example.com"
_user = "root"
_password = "ready"
_timeout = 10

ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect(_host, username=_user, password=_password, timeout=_timeout)
```

---

and second module(contains only one line of import)

### runner.py:

```
from module_for_importing import *
```

---

so, magic start when I try to run 
python2.7 runner.py
I got an exception in method ssh.connect():

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:/testing/runner.py", line 1, in <module>
    from module_for_importing import *
  File "E:\testing\module_for_importing.py", line 13, in <module>
    ssh.connect(_host, username=_user, password=_password, timeout=_timeout)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\paramiko\client.py", line 398, in connect
    server_key = t.get_remote_server_key()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\paramiko\transport.py", line 720, in get_remote_server_key
    raise SSHException('No existing session')
paramiko.ssh_exception.SSHException: No existing session
```

but if start python module:
python2.7 module_for_importing.py

all work fine.

Could you please help me to understand root cause of the exception? 
for python 3, there is no any errors.

Comment: Exactly the same problem here! Very weird!

Answer (score 2):

You want to create a proper object for ssh:

```
import paramiko


class SSH(object):

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def est_conn(self, ip, username, password):
        ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
        ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.WarningPolicy())
        ssh.connect(ip, username=username, password=password)
        print("Asserting that ssh connection has been established...")
        assert ssh

        return ssh

ssh = SSH()
```

and then in your runner.py use:

```
from module_for_importing import ssh
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: ok, create class SSH, resolve the problem.

But if it is possible, could you please explain case when I start script that contains imported module, and it's raised exception, 
but if start the python module independently, it's work fine?
is it related with how python imports modules, there are excistense some rules?

Comment: Yes, it is related to how python treats objects. You might have heard that "everything in Python is an object" mantra. While that is correct, in python, classes are a higher abstraction of an object. In you code you was using * to import everything from module_for_importing.py, that meant you've imported all variables as separate objects. In my code I've wrapped all these variables into a single object known as SSH, and its parameters were all the variables from your code inside est_conn method of SSH() object. Hope this explanation helps.

Comment: @JonasM Your solution has helped, thank you! Sadly, I still don't understand your explanation. What does inheritance (higher abstraction of an object) have to do with a module failing? The only explanation I have is that paramiko reaches into a certain object space to get hold of the ssh session (running as a subprocess?), and if imported "the wrong way" the session ends up elsewhere. Could you please explain what is happening here?